# Blocking IO (OIO) UDT Channel in Netty

Tags: java, netty, nio, blocking, udp-data-transfer

I'd like to use Netty's implementation of UDT on a Blocking IO Channel. I already have a working NIO UDT implementation where Netty have a proper channels on NIO. I couldn't find an appropriate channel for OIO, It would be great if someone help me with a proper Blocking IO UDT channel in Netty.

Comment: Is this Java-specific? If so please tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no blocking UDT transport in Netty. If there is a good reason to add the old-I/O UDT transport, please let us know.